# Uploading a file to AWS S3 with ACL set to public_read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, acl, aws-sdk

In my Rails app I save customer RMA shipping labels to an S3 bucket on creation.  I just updated to V2 of the aws-sdk gem, and now my code for setting the ACL doesn't work.

Code that worked in V1.X:

```
  # Saves label to S3 bucket
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  obj = s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']].objects["#{shippinglabel_filename}"]
  obj.write(open(label.label('pdf').postage_label.label_pdf_url, 'rb'), :acl => :public_read)
```

`.write` seems to have been deprecated, so I'm using `.put` now.  Everything is working, except when I try to set the ACL.

New code for V2.0:

```
  # Saves label to S3 bucket
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
  obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object("#{shippinglabel_filename}")
  obj.put(Base64.decode64(label_base64), { :acl => :public_read })
```

I get an `Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument` error, pointed at the ACL.

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument is the bulk of the message.  The console just points towards my Model at the obj.put line.  Can post a screenshot if that would be helpful.

Comment: I was wondering if it was some hint about the error, such as the format of the argument or that not being allowed or such. No worries.

Answer (score 22):

This code works for me:

```
photo_obj = bucket.object object_name
photo_obj.upload_file path, {acl: 'public-read'}
```

so you need to use the string 'public-read' for the acl.  I found this by seeing an example in object.rb

Comment: You rock - thanks!  I can't believe it was just a hyphen instead of an underscore.  I actually switched back to the old API because of this - but now I know how to upgrade.  Thanks!

Comment: Ack!  Same here -- I had an underscore, too.  Double-checked the official docs three times without catching my error!

Comment: yep, the hyphen works, *thank you*. I'm using Python/boto3 and had the same problem, now mostly solved. still problem with mime-type, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? Was stuck for hours until i stumbled across this answer.